# Delphi Indy OPENSSL_Uplink exception

Tags: delphi, indy

Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, integrated Indy, Windows 7 64 bit, OpenSSL DLLS V1.0.2c,

Sometimes, when using proxies, I get an exception where a dialop popup with the caption OpenSSL:FATAL and the text "OPENSSL_Uplink(a long number): no OPENSSL_Applink" and my app crash due to this.

Does anybody know what this could be and what I could be to solve this?

Comment: Not sure if this is related to the error, but OpenSSL 1.0.2c is three years old (https://www.openssl.org/news/openssl-1.0.2-notes.html), try a newer version

Comment: This exact error is covered in the OpenSSL FAQs: [I've compiled a program under Windows and it crashes: why?](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#PROG3). Which DLLs exactly are you using? The DLLs available from [Indy's Fulgan mirror](https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL) do not have this error (the latest available at this time is 1.0.2o)

Comment: I am using 1.0.2c of ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll, both are fileversion 1.0.2.3. I will try with the 1.0.2o and hope it will fix the issue. It does not have any issue on Windows 10 or Server 2008, but with a couple of clients using Windows 7.